# How to fix error abandoned fzaninotto/faker packagist in composer 2.0.11 version and i used php 8.0.0?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

How to fix fzaninotto/faker packagist
"This package is abandoned and no longer maintained. No replacement package was suggested."
in composer 2.0.11 version and i used php 8.0.0?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You can still use the package, even if that is no longer maintained

Comment: @NicoHaase You are right; this is only a warning. The wording of the question "fix" is a bit misleading since it implies something is broken. I would say the question is about "resolving" this warning.

Answer (score 45):

The quick way is

```
composer remove fzaninotto/faker
```

Then install

```
composer require fakerphp/faker --dev
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the new package faker (fork).

Remove the faker abandoned

```
composer remove vendor/fzaninotto/faker
```

Install the new package

```
composer require fakerphp/faker
```

And replace it in your composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.13.0",
}
```

Comment: The easier way would be to just place it in your `require-dev` directly via the command with the `--dev` option. Which makes the full command: `composer require fakerphp/faker --dev`